# How to setup Datatables for a servlet and object array?

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, servlets, datatable

I have a servlet that returns a collection of model bean objects to a jsp page.  From there I want to display that data, but I'm not sure of the correct way to do it.

The average number of rows returned from the database will probably be less than a few hundred at best.

I'm using Java 1.6 and the default jQuery with Datatables 1.10.4.

I did verify that the data is in the collection and that it goes out in the request to the JSP page.

Originally, I had hard coded values for the data to make sure I had the datatable setup properly, based on [Javascript Sourced Data](https://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html) from the Datatables site, but now I have actual data and I'm not sure how to get it in the table properly.

Here is my new jQuery code that is showing this error here in Eclipse:

```
 "ajax': './MyServlet", //invalid property assignment error?
```

I'm not sure what that error means?

```
 <!-- jQuery code -->
     $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#datatable').dataTable({
                "processing": true,
                "ajax': './MyServlet", 
                "columns": [
                { "data": "Last Name" },
                { "data": "First Name" },
                { "data": "Mailing Address" },
                ...
            ]
            });
        });
```

Here is my HTML datatable code with scriptlets, for now to loop through my collection of objects and add in columns/rows.  I saw this in another example, so I used it just trying to get it working.

```
<!-- The datatable in the jsp page -->
<table width="100%" id="datatable" class="display compact" cellspacing="0">
        <%
            if(null != modelBeanCollection  && modelBeanCollection.size() > 0) {
        %>

        <%
            List<modelBean> projectList = (List<modelBean>)(List<?>) modelBeanCollection;
            for (modelBean project : projectList) { 
        %>
        <tr>
            <td><%=project.getLastName()%></td>
            <td><%=project.getFirstName()%></td>
            <td><%=project.getAddress1()%></td>
            ...
        </tr>
            <%}
        }%>

</table>
```

My main question is, what is the best practice to display an array of objects in a jsp page, with what I have, using datatables, based on a few hundred rows of data?

Comment: `"ajax': './MyServlet"` you have single quotes in here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking at your code, you are trying to initale the datatables with an ajax call and at the same time with the whole data from jsp scriptlet.

In your case I don't think the ajax part is needed. Here is what I'd do;

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            /* Column names goes here for header */
            <th>A</th>
            <th>B</th>
               ....
        </tr>
    </thead>

  <tbody>
     <%
        if(null != modelBeanCollection  && modelBeanCollection.size() > 0) {
    %>

    <%
        List<modelBean> projectList = (List<modelBean>)(List<?>) modelBeanCollection;
        for (modelBean project : projectList) { 
    %>
    <tr>
        <td><%=project.getLastName()%></td>
        <td><%=project.getFirstName()%></td>
        <td><%=project.getAddress1()%></td>
        ...
    </tr>
        <%}
    }%>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And at the `$(document).ready` event just a simple initialize statement like this;

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "processing": true
} );
```

And you are set!

Also I'd like to suggest you to use EL for JSP pages, it'll save you a lot of headaches and it's so much easier to use. The above scriptlet could be written just like this:

```
    <c:if test="{not empty modelBeanCollection}">
      <c:forEach items="${modelBeanCollection}" var="project">
        <tr>
              <td>${project.getLastName}></td>
              <td>${project.getFirstName}></td>
              <td>${project.getAddress1}</td>
              ...
          </tr>
      </c:forEach>
    </c:if>
```

Comment: Yes I will use JSTL, but I'm just trying to get it working.  This fixes my syntax issue, but I have to fix my Collection to a list cast exception now.  Thanks!